# Avoid null in least function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have this query

```
select least(                                                              
    (select min(full_date) from lopes.vehicle_data),
    (select min(bithday) from lopes.ad_trf_day),
    (select min(bithday) from lopes.ad_day_rec),
    (select min(bithday) from lopes.ad_day_rec),
    (select min(bithday) from lopes.ad_day),
    (select min(bithday) from lopes.ad_poi_day))
from dual
```

but it returns NULL. Is there a way to avoid nulls ?

Comment: Check out `coalesce()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to avoid using `LEAST`:

```
SELECT MIN( dt )
FROM   (
  SELECT full_date FROM lopes.vehicle_data UNION ALL
  SELECT bithday FROM lopes.ad_trf_day UNION ALL
  SELECT bithday FROM lopes.ad_day_rec UNION ALL
  SELECT bithday FROM lopes.ad_day_rec UNION ALL
  SELECT bithday FROM lopes.ad_day UNION ALL
  SELECT bithday FROM lopes.ad_poi_day
)
```

This will still return `NULL` but only if all of the tables are either empty or only contain `NULL` values.

Another is to use `COALESCE`, `NVL` or `CASE`:

```
select least(                                                              
         (select COALESCE( min(full_date), DATE '9999-12-31' ) from lopes.vehicle_data),
         (select COALESCE( min(bithday), DATE '9999-12-31' ) from lopes.ad_trf_day),
         (select COALESCE( min(bithday), DATE '9999-12-31' ) from lopes.ad_day_rec),
         (select COALESCE( min(bithday), DATE '9999-12-31' ) from lopes.ad_day_rec),
         (select COALESCE( min(bithday), DATE '9999-12-31' ) from lopes.ad_day),
         (select COALESCE( min(bithday), DATE '9999-12-31' ) from lopes.ad_poi_day)
       )
from dual
```

This will never return `NULL` but would return the "magic" value `DATE '9999-12-31'` if all the tables are either empty or only contain `NULL` values.

Comment: instead of the coalesce, I did a ifnull(birthday, '9999-12-31')

Comment: @GenDemo `IFNULL` is not a valid Oracle function and `'9999-12-31'` is not a `DATE` data type it is a string. I am guessing that you are working in a different RDBMS.

Comment: it works on snowflake  (both the function and the date)  :)
and the date works on TSQL as well   :)

Comment: oh I see the question has oracle tagged - appologies, I didn't see that. This thread came up when I searched for snowflake.